# How to use Adminer Editor with SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to use the 'light' version of Adminer called **Adminer Editor** to access a SQLite3 database file in the same directory.

The [documentation](https://www.adminer.org/en/extension/) on the [official website](https://www.adminer.org/en/) doesn't seem to be too extensive and <s>I am still trying</s> it took me a long time to find a working solution.

I was able to overcome the `None of the supported PHP extensions (SQLite3, PDO_SQLite) are available.` error.

Later I was stuck at the `Database does not support password.` error.

After this I was confronted with the `attempt to write a readonly database` error.

I hope my experience will help other people using adminer editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*My system is Manjaro based on Archlinux, some of the commands might be different for your system.*

1. Install php-sqlite: `sudo pacman -S php-sqlite`
2. Activate the SQLite driver for php by editing `/etc/php/php.ini`:
   uncomment the line `;extension=sqlite3` by removing the `;`.
3. Restart apache, in my case: `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`.
4. You can check if SQLite is active in php by writing `<?php phpinfo();` into a php file and open it in your browser.
5. Download the adminer-editor source file from the [Adminer Editor page](https://www.adminer.org/en/editor/) and rename it to `adminer-editor.php`.
6. Download `plugin.php` and `login-password-less.php` from the [Plugins page](https://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/) and put them into the `plugins` subfolder.
7. If you don't have a SQLite database file you can create it with `sqlite3 database.db` in terminal.
8. Download the `sqlite.php` file from the [adminer github repository](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/master/editor/sqlite.php) and save it as `index.php`.
9. Your folder structure should be like this:

```
    adminer-editor.php
    database.db
    index.php
    plugins/
           |__ login-password-less.php
           |__ plugin.php
```

10. Edit your `index.php` file. The content of my file is this:

```php
<?php
function adminer_object() {
  
  include_once "plugins/plugin.php";
  include_once "plugins/login-password-less.php";
  
    class AdminerCustomization extends AdminerPlugin {
        function loginFormField($name, $heading, $value) {
            return parent::loginFormField($name, $heading, str_replace('value="server"', 'value="sqlite"', $value));
        }
        function database() {
            return "database.db";
        }
    }
    
    return new AdminerCustomization(array(
        // TODO: inline the result of password_hash() so that the password is not visible in source codes
        new AdminerLoginPasswordLess(password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)),
    ));
}
include 'adminer-editor.php';
```

11. You can now browse to your index.php, leave the Username field empty and enter the password equal to the one in your `index.php`.

---

**edit**: Some things to note:

- The folder containing the SQLite database file must give appropriate write permissions so that a lock file can be created next to the database file at any time you are using it. A good solution might be to put the database file in its own subfolder. Make sure that the file itself can not be accessed from the web, maybe using .htaccess and/or .htpasswd files.
- Some text editors will break the translation functionality in the adminer php files after editing them. If this happens to you, re-download the original file and use a different editor. In my case, `micro` did break them, `nano` didn't.

---

Some questions that are left on my side:

- Is there a way to set different Usernames for different users?
- What does the `// TODO` line mean; Is there a way that I don't have to store the password in plain text in my `index.php` file?
- Any other improvements you would like to suggest?

Comment: i nned to install `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3`